# Superscript for a variable

Tags: python, variables, unicode, superscript

I want to print out a variable as a superscript. I have done a lot of research and lots of people use the method of Unicode. Which is something like `print("word\u00b2")` where the 2 will be in superscript. However, I want to replace the 2 with a variable. These are the methods I have tried

```
print("word\u00b{variable}")
print("word\u00b{}".format(variable))
print("word\u00b%s" % variable)
```

and of course with the back slash

```
print("word\u00b\{variable}")
print("word\u00b\{}".format(variable))
print("word\u00b\%s" % variable)
```

As well, I have also tried something like

```
variable = variable.decode(u\"u00b")
```

None of the above worked as I kept getting

```
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 5-9: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Some help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escape code `\u00b2` is a single character; you want something like

```
>>> print(eval(r'"\u00b' + str(2) + '"'))
²
```

Less convolutedly,

```
>>> print(chr(0x00b2))
²
```

This only works for superscript 2 and 3, though; the [other Unicode superscripts are in a different code block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block).

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...   if i == 1:
...     print(chr(0x00b9))
...   elif 2 <= i <= 3:
...     print(chr(0x00b0 + i))
...   else:
...     print(chr(0x2070 + i))
⁰
¹
²
³
⁴
⁵
⁶
⁷
⁸
⁹
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your entire variable to be superscripted you have to use the `%` format.  If you try to `.format()` it, it will only superscript the first letter or number because it uses brackets to group numbers inside of the `$$`.

I wrote my code like this:

```
print(r'$y=%f*x^{%f}$' % (var_A, var_B)
```

This way you do not have to call Unicode.  I found this method worked for graph titles, axis titles, graph legends.

I hope this helps!